# NetTcpBinding with Transport mode and ClientCridentialType None mode asking for certificate to start the host

Tags: .net, wcf, security

Is that really not possible to use Transport security for netTcpBinding with None authentication? I really don't want to use any certificate for my service, I used below we config for my service and when i am starting my service host i am getting application error i mentioned below(asking for certificate, i didn't even mention about certificate anywhere in app). However after i put the service credentials in the behavior , service start running. Can anyone tell me whats the cause for this?

***Error : "The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials. "***

```
 <service name="ConsoleApplication1.WCFService1" behaviorConfiguration="" >
                <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:853/WCFService1" binding="netTcpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="SecurityCheckBinding"  name="TCPEndpoint" contract="ConsoleApplication1.IService1" />

                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:853/WCFService1" />

                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>

            </service>



<bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
          <binding name="SecurityCheckBinding">
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None"  ></transport>
            </security>
          </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
      </bindings>
```

This scenario i was getting above mentioned error, but when i just specified the trusted certificate params , it start running.

```
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyServiceBehaviour">
        <serviceCredentials>
          <serviceCertificate findValue="MyTestCA" x509FindType="FindByIssuerName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
        </serviceCredentials>

      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

Comment: + this is a comment i found from WCF security Guide - **None. When using this option, the WCF service does not authenticate the callers. This is not the recommended option from security perspective — avoid using this option wherever possible. **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you selected NetTpcBinding with Transport security, you stated that channel must be secured on the transport level. For this purpose you should use either Windows SSPI mechanism or generate a Certificate which would be used for the encryption. 
The first option assumes that you use Windows credentials to make the Encryption processed internally by SSPI libaraies by setting:

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Windows"></transport>
```

In this case the proccess will be transparent, but in case when your client is on the other domain, you have to apply extra cross-domain trust settings.
Another option is installing certificate, which is quite easy and has lots of examples in the internat:

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>
```

The certificate is auto-signed (generated on the server itself) so it doesn't cost you some money an you need it on the server only - clients need not install anything.

Even if you state None credentials, you still need to provide certificat for the encryption:

```
<transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
```

And you still have an option to not to use the security, then your massages will be in the plane text. To turn off security just change transport security by setting:

```
<security mode="None">
```

Comment: thats great, but did you mean netTcpBinding? you mentioned NetHttpBinding  above. and your answer perfectly make sense but can you share  me any reference for ?

Comment: so by default NetTcpBinding not doing encrypt and sign ?

Comment: I had the same problem and I used to look for many google and msdn faqs and links :) When you set your security as Transport (or Message), you make you service required to implement the security mechanism. In http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731316.aspx it is said that Transport security is provided using TLS over TCP or SPNego (HTTP - SSL). But all these protocols require certificate!!! So without it they wouldn't be able to work.

Comment: The default NetTcpBinding security is Transport and required to have a certificate (see prev link). You can set Security Mode to None, if you don't want to use such security mechanism (server-side certificate requirement)